# Unexpected behavior of pipes with scanf()

Tags: c, unix, pipe, cygwin, scanf

It's been a while since I last programmed in C, and I'm having trouble making pipes work. (For sake of clarity, I'm using Cygwin on Windows 7.) In particular, I need help understanding the behavior of the following example:

```c
/* test.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main() {

    char c;
    //scanf("%c", &c); // this is problematic

    int p[2];
    pipe(p);

    int out = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);

    // from now on, implicitly read from and write on pipe
    dup2(p[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(p[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    printf("hello");
    fflush(stdout);

    // restore stdout
    dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO);
    // should read from pipe and write on stdout
    putchar(getchar());
    putchar(getchar());
    putchar(getchar());
}
```

If I invoke:

```
echo abcde | ./test.exe
```

I get the following output:

```
hel
```

However, if I uncomment the `scanf` call, I get:

```
bcd
```

Which I can't explain. This is actually a very simplified version of a more complex program with a `fork/exec` structure that started behaving very bad. Despite not having cycles, it somehow began spawning infinite children in an endless loop. So, rules permitting, I'll probably need to extend the question with a more concrete case of use. Many thanks.

Comment: scanf reads a bunch of data from stdin (probably 4096 or 8192 bytes) before you manipulate the file descriptors.

Comment: Ok but what has that to do with the pipes? If you mean that `p[0]` "starts" with that bunch of data, how should I fix it?

Comment: No, p[0] doesn't start with the data.  The data is in the stdio buffer, and first call to getchar is going to look at that buffer without ever reading from the pipe.

Comment: Now it's clear, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stream I/O functions such as `scanf` generally perform buffering to improve performance.  Thus, if you call `scanf` on the standard input then it will probably read more characters than needed to satisfy the request, and the extra will be waiting, buffered, for the next read.

Swapping out the the underlying file descriptor does not affect previously buffered data.  When you subsequently read the file again, you get data buffered the first time until those are exhausted, and only then do you get fresh data from the new underlying file.

If you wish, you can turn off buffering of a stream via the `setvbuf()` function, before any I/O operations have been performed on it:

```
int result = setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
if (result != 0) {
    // handle error ...
}
```

> This is actually a very simplified version of a more complex program
>   with a fork/exec structure that started behaving very bad. Despite not
>   having cycles, it somehow began spawning infinite children in an
>   endless loop.

I don't see how that behavior would be related to what you've asked here.

> So, rules permitting, I'll probably need to extend the
>   question with a more concrete case of use.

That would be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks. Just out of curiosity, is there another way? What if I want to retain the buffering? Edit: Also, does it affect child processes, too? I mean. is the buffer copied when the process is forked?

Comment: Regarding the child processes, yes, apparently.

Comment: Yes, @giofrida, the buffer is in the process's memory, and therefore is copied upon a `fork()`.  This is a sometime-source of bugs in its own right.

Comment: As for another way, I'm not sure I understand: If you're going to use the stdio functions then you have to take buffering into account (on a stream-by-stream basis).  You have a choice between three buffering styles, with one of them being "none".  Or on a system that supports `fork()`, you probably also have the low-level `read()` and `write()` functions.  These leave it to you to do buffering if you want it.

Comment: The parent should read `stdin` line by line and pass them each time to a new child (yes, there'd be a cycle, but I hadn't been able to implement the full program). However, before the child `exec`utes on its line, it has to reinject a part of it to `stdin` (via pipes) because that's how the sub-program works and I can't change it. Anyways, I opted for disabling the buffering altogether. Edit: If there's another way to do this, I'd love to know.

Comment: @giofrida, I'm having trouble seeing how what you describe -- specifically, the "reinjecting" part -- could be made to work.  I think you will save yourself a lot of grief by putting the responsibility *on the parent* to identify and properly handle that part of its input that should be re-used.  Alternatively, have the children pipe it back to the parent without trying to redirect that to stdin.

Comment: No, I meant that the sub-program `exec`uted by the child has to re-read part of the line from `stdin`, after a little pre-process, so the child opens a pipe just for that, with the scheme of the above example (imagine to replace `"hello"` with that part of the line, and the subsequent calls to `getchar()` as the sub-program `exec`uting).

Comment: Then your example is not representative of your objective.  Streams' buffers are in their processes' memory, and so are copied over a `fork()`, but all of that is *replaced* by any of the exec-family functions.  The execed process inherits open file descriptors, including those underlying the standard streams, but not streams or their buffers.

Comment: Then why does it work...I really don't want to bother you further, but should I open another question?

Comment: Yes, I think you should pose another question.  I have answered the one you asked, but it now seems like that wasn't what you really wanted to know.